# How does "property" work in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how the `property` decorator works in Python.

So,

```
 class Foo:

 def method(self,param):
    self._method(param)

 @property
 def _method(self): # works fine.. why... I havent defined this to accept any argument
    #some logic
    #even though it passes.. how do i retrieve "param" parameter passed above?
```

vs.:

```
 class Foo:

 def method(self,param):
    self._method(param)

 # no property decorator here (throws error)
 def _method(self):
    #some logic
```

If the decorator `property` is removed, Python throws an error, which is fine, as I am passing an argument which is not accepted in the method.  I understand that, but why doesn't `_method(self)` need any more params with `property` defined?

And how do I retrieve the `param` value inside `method` using decorator approach?

Comment: Rename it to `@property
 def _method(x)` and see if it still works

Comment: @TimCastelijns: But thats not what I want to know.. What I want to know is why does it succeeds.. and how do i retreive that parameter?

Comment: Why do you want `_method` to be a `@property`? Why not leave it as a method, and define the parameter you want `def _method(self, param):`? What are you trying to achieve? It would generally help if you provided code that runs and a precise definition of the problem (an error - where's the traceback).

Comment: I am trying to understand why this particular code works..

Comment: But you're saying it doesn't work - you either get an error, or can't access the parameter. Again, *what are you trying to achieve*?!

Comment: Yeah.. I mean, why does adding a decorator "property" makes the function definition list not to have the argument list..

Comment: I am just trying to understand the concept.. really

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually runs? Also, are these old-style or new-style classes - which version of Python are you using?

Comment: The example I wrote runs on my python repl??

Comment: That may be so, but the example you've *posted* is incorrectly indented, has comments where code should be and doesn't include any input data (what is `param` anyway?)

Comment: This helped me understand how the property decorator functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/python-how-does-the-property-decorator-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what `self._method(param)` actually does when `_method` is a `property`. Since you are dealing with a property, the value currently stored in the property is retrieved.

```
tmp = self._method
```

And then that value is called as a function.

```
tmp(param)
```

Therefore there is no way to retrieve the value of `param` in the getter for `_method` since the interpreter hasn't even gotten to the point where `param` even matters.